# How can I find after how many sales a product becomes best seller?

Tags: best-seller

It is kind a silly question (I know), but where can I find after how many sales a product becomes a **Bestseller**?

Comment: Can u please tell  me how you define a product is for best seller

Comment: That is exactly what I am asking!

Comment: I think products are "bestsellers" based on how many of them were ordered. I believe they're just sorted by decreasing number of sales (but I might be wrong).

Answer (score 1):

Depends on over setting..
Using time period we can set how many days ordered best selling products. 
Ex: If I set 5 in the time period then it will display best selling products which will be sold in the last 5 days. If no value set then it will display last 60 days best selling products.

Also go through the link..
https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/best-seller-products-extension.html